# Bash rename multiple files according to line in another file

Tags: linux, bash, rename, file-rename

I would like to rename multiple files according to the name specified in another file.
For example, I have a file called ***names.txt***, containing:

```
Name1 Newname1
Name2 Newname2
Name3 Newname3
```

etc

In this ***names.txt*** file the names are not numbered. However, the name in column 1 and column 2 are linked together. 
I can imaging it should be possible to loop through the file to extract both names and use it in the ***mv*** function somehow.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming none of the names in `names.txt` contains whitespace, you can use this:

```
while read a b; do mv "$a" "$b"; done < names.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work even if you have space :

```
SAVE_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for row in `cat names.txt`
do
    echo $row
    cur_name=`echo $row | awk -F " " '{print $1}'`
    new_name=`echo $row | awk -F " " '{print $2}'`
    echo "mv $cur_name $new_name"
done
IFS=$SAVE_IFS
```

Comment: This won't work. What input you used?. It is bad idea to use for and cat

Comment: @MaheshKharvi, How do you think we can loop through a file when using a for loop.

Comment: for loop treats entire file content as stream of strings and cant handle if lines contain space. You can use while loop to read entire line as single input or multiple.

`while IFS= read -r a b; do
echo $a $b
done < <file>`

Comment: Hi @MaheshKharvi , i agree with you it can done well with "while". But still we can do with for loop  which i have updated and it runs fine.